# RESTful collections & controlling member details

Tags: http, rest, data-structures, collections

I have come across this issue a few times now, and each time I make a fruitless search to come up with a satisfying answer.

We have a collection resource which returns a representation of the member URIs, as well as a `Link` header field with the same URIs (and a custom relation type). Often we find that we need specific data from each member in the collection.

- At one extreme, we can have the collection return nothing but the member URIs; the client must then query each URI in turn to determine the required data from each member.
- At the other extreme, we return all of the details we might want on the collection. Neither of these is perfect; the first can result in a large number of API calls, and the second may return a lot of potentially unneeded information.

Of the two extremes I favour the second in our case, since we rarely use this for more than one sutiation. However, for a more general approach, I wondered if anyone had a nice way of dynamically specifying which details should be included for each member of the collection? I guess a query string parameter would be most appropriate, but I don't want to break the self-descriptiveness of the resource.

Comment: *[Years later]* Sounds like I wanted GraphQL…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to reinvent PROPFIND ([RFC 4918, Section 9.1](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9.1)).

Comment: Thanks — that's exactly what I was looking for; I hadn't thought about looking to WebDAV.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer your first option..

> At one extreme, we can have the
>   collection return nothing but the
>   member URIs; the client must then
>   query each URI in turn to determine
>   the required data from each member.

If you are wanting to reduce the number of HTTP calls over the wire, for example calling a service from a handset app (iOS/Android). You can include an additional header to include the child resources:

`X-Aggregate-Resources-Depth: 2`

Your server side code will have to aggregate the resources to the desired depth.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly contain a subset of elements in each item within a collection resource.  How you define the different subsets is really up to you.  Whether you do,

```
/mycollectionwithjustlinks
/mycollectionwithsubsetA 
/mycollectionwithsubsetB
```

or you use query strings

```
/mycollection?itemfields=foo,bar,baz
```

either way they are all different resources.  I'm not sure why you believe this is affecting the self-descriptive constraint.

Comment: Perhaps my issue is more about the _discoverability_ of those resources. I'd ideally like the /mycollection resource indicate to the client the available itemfields that it may choose from.

Comment: @cbuckley Your collection could contain a special ItemTemplate element that contained a list of available fields that can be included.

Comment: I don't think it belongs in the body unless the client has requested that information. I could use a custom response header to identify them, but that really would break self-descriptiveness. The best I have come up with is a parameter to `Content-Type`, i.e. `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8; aggregate=foo,bar,baz`. The client would then use the `Accept` header field.